# How to manage some of the containers started by docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have configured 1 nginx, 3 tomcat(each have a webapp) and 1 mysql container with the docker compose ,and all these 5 containers are started with `docker-compose up` , they work well.

After running for serveral days, I need to upgrade my webapp(tomcat container), no change for the nginx and mysql container.

I would ask what's the process to do upgrade for only the tomcat containers? Should I also stop the nginx and mysql container as well to do the upgrade and then start all these containers again weith docker compose? Since only tomcat/webapp need  to be upgraded. Ideally, I don't need to start nginx and mysql container at all.

I google searched the internet, almost all the meterials there are about how to configure with docker compose, but none about how to manage only part of the containers started up by docker compose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker Compose is a container orchestration tool. The idea is to stop and start containers in tandem so they don't run into errors because some container was not started. If you are going to pull the latest images for the web app(I'm assuming that's what you meant by *upgrade*), you can stop all the containers with `docker-compose stop` and then run `docker pull` for the web app images.

Then you can run `docker-compose up` to bring up all the containers. You don't need to *upgrade* any other container.

Comment: Thanks @thegeorgeous for the great answer. one more question here, when using docker-compose up again, the nginx container and mysql container are new containers? that is, the container id is differnent from the stopped nginx/mysql containers?

Comment: Depends on how you have configured docker-compose. If you have build option configured, it will rebuild images and create a new container every time. If not it will restart existing containers